# Can a foreign key use unique index?

Tags: mysql

I created a unique index on a column, and then added a foreign key using ALTER TABLE. MySQL added a non-unique index on top of my unique index to the column. Is the non-unique index necessary? Does it speed things up in any way?

Comment: Why did you create a unique index on the column that contains the foreign key instead of relying on the unique constraint that presumably exists in the linked table?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins to ensure "Something" is only mapped one time to "Something else"?

Comment: The foreign key and index were added to another column apart from the primary key. The unusual behavior described above happened on the referencing table (child table).

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Forgot to tag you.

Answer (score 1):

`Does it speed things up in any way?`

First, Indexes do not always speed things up. Indexes are slowing down update, insert and delete statements, because the index has to be updated along with the data.

Second, there are scenarios, where the mysql-optimizer might decide to use a wrong index, and using another Index might be faster.

`Is the non-unique index necessary?`

No. See also the mysql documentation about YOUR usecase, if you would have done it the other way round:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the
>   referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
>   columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an
>   index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
>   exist. **This index might be silently dropped later, if you create
>   another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key constraint.**

Comment: Thanks for your response. I read that article. The index existed before the unique key was added to that table, so MySQL should have had a chance to evaluate the index already. It added the key because MySQL felt it was necessary, for some reason. I would like to know why a non-unique index is required over a unique index.

Comment: @Waffles The question is if mysql REALLY evaluated existing indexes or if it just said: *Me need index, ME CREATE!!* (Sometimes you shouldn't expect tooo much)